# pipenv: How does pipenv calculate that pipfile.lock is out of date

Tags: pipenv

Q1: How does `pipenv` determine that `pipfile.lock` is out of date?

Q2: If I don't manually modify the `Pipfile`, will `Pipfile.lock` ever be outdated?

Q3: Will `Pipfile.lock` always be updated after I install a package?